# Error when a command is ran from bash script but not from terminal

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

So I have created a script that installs mysql and I am trying to run the script.sql file from the bash script. The script has a function log() that runs these commands. Script is like below:

```
log() {
    echo -e "\n[$1]" >> output.txt
    # Execute the provided command
     $1 >> output.txt 2>&1

    # Check the exit status of the command
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        echo -e "$2"
    else
        echo "Error on command: [$1]"
    fi
}

#
#...... Mysql installation commands run in the same way as below 
#
log 'sudo mysql -e "source /home/albi/Desktop/Bash_scripts/script.sql;"' "[CREATED MYSQL USER]\n"
```

The error that I get in the output.txt is `ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database '/home/albi/Desktop/Bash_scripts/script.sql;"'`

But when I run this command `sudo mysql -e "source /home/albi/Desktop/Bash_scripts/script.sql;"` in terminal it is ran successfully with no errors. Any idea what might be causing this or any suggestions ?

A little bit of explanation of what I am trying to do with script. So basically I have created a function log() that executes the first parameter given which is a terminal command and the second argument will be displayed into the terminal upon successful completion. It looks like this: log '*command*' '*message*'. The output of the command is appended in the output.txt and if return code of the command executed is 0 the message provided will be shown in terminal else in terminal will be shown the problematic command.

Comment: Don't store commands in variables. You can't do that. Let me find the duplicate of this question, it has been asked many times before.

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050